# File transformation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Good day.

Please someone who can help me with the code to transform the following structure

I should read the source database and then search the database target, if the database target does not exist, I must create it.

## BDD source

```
 **DB:source_1
 Collection: temp1**

 "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6999ce58dedb9bc00fb27")
 "machine" : 323,
 "name_art" : "XXXX",
 "sku" : "12345",
 "name" : "Luis"
 "turno" : 1
 "codigo" : "P08",
 "time1" : 10:10



 "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6999ce58dedb9bc00fb27")
 "machine" : 323,
 "name_art" : "XXXX",
 "sku" : "1567",
 "name" : "Joan"
 "turno" : 2
 "codigo" : "P09",
 "time1" : 20:20


 **transform for**
```

#BDD target

```
 DB:  target1
 Collection: dat_end

 "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6999ce58dedb9bc00fb27")
 "machine" : 323,
 "name_art" : "XXXX",
 "worked" : [
       {
             "sku" : "12345",
             "name" : "Luis"
             "turno" : 1
     },
     {
             "sku" : "1567",
             "name" : "Joan"
             "turno" : 2
     }
  ]
  "paros" : [
     {
             "codigo" : "P08",
             "time1" : 10:10
     },
     {
             "codigo" : "P09",
             "time1" : 20:20
     }
 ]
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You could probably do that with aggregation, but the question does not specify what  transformations you want to make on the data.  Could you edit those details in?  All of the _id values in these objects are the same, is that how you plan to matched them?

Comment: Thanks Joe!!! 
by mistake put the same _id but in reality they are different
The idea is: read a DB-Source sequentially and for each document read check if the document exists in DB-target1 (the key would be machine + name_art), if the document exists it must update its values, if it does not exist it creates a new document

if the document exists, it must verify if the worked exists, if the worked exists it must update its values, otherwise it must create a new worked